# double pointers in C programming

Tags: c, pointers

I have a statement which I need help with:

```
int  i=2, j=5, *p = &j, *q = &i;
```

and this is the question..

```
&i == p    //is this true?
7 * *q / *p + 3    //is this legal?
```

I am pretty sure the second statement is illegal but I don't know why? can anyone please explain me this.

Comment: Why the sudden change of question? If you're asking a new question, please ask it *as* a new question.

Comment: @user2962635: Never radically rewrite the question. Do as computerfreak said instead if you have a new question. Did a rollback.

Comment: sorry i will delete this question and ask a new one.. i wrote the question wrong..

Answer (score 0):

Second statement is equivalent to

```
( (7 * *q) / *p ) + 3
```

In sub-expression `(7 * *q) / *p`, first `*` (from left to right) is for *multiplication* and second is for *dereference*.

Comment: Are you sure it's not `[(7 * *q) / *p] + 3`? Seems to me that operator precedence would dictate `/` before `+`, and there are no parentheses to change that.

Comment: @computerfreaker; Oops! Edited that :)

Comment: sorry question was wrong i changed it.. sorry for inconvenience.